# how to vertically place item center of the screen using tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am making form in next.js and i am unable to place the form vertically in the center of the screen. I am using one way that allows me to center it but it changes my form original size

**the code without center of screen**

```
import React from "react";

function SignUp() {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-gray-50 pt-5 ">
      <form className=" grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-9  rounded-xl  shadow-xl  bg-gray-50 max-w-sm mx-auto  ">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-purple-600 ">
          SignUp{" "}
          <span className="text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
            to Trading Application
          </span>
        </h1>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Company Name..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Username..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Email..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Password..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Confirm Password..."
          />
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-purple mt-3 rounded-full">
          Create Account
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignUp;
```

**code with center of screen trick but **`this trick changes the size of my form`****

```
<div className="h-screen bg-gray-50 pt-5 grid grid-cols-1">
      <form className="place-self-center grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-9  rounded-xl  shadow-xl  bg-gray-50 max-w-sm mx-auto  ">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-purple-600 ">
          SignUp{" "}
          <span className="text-sm font-normal text-gray-400">
            to Trading Application
          </span>
        </h1>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Company Name..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Username..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Email..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Password..." />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Confirm Password..."
          />
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-purple mt-3 rounded-full">
          Create Account
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

tailwind code for *`btn, btn-purple`* & *`input`*

```
@layer components {
  
  .input {
    @apply border border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:border-transparent shadow-md rounded-lg px-3 py-2 w-full font-light
    transition duration-300;
  }
  .btn {
    @apply rounded-md py-2 px-3 border-transparent focus:outline-none  transition duration-500 uppercase font-medium;
  }
  .btn-purple {
    @apply bg-purple-600 text-white hover:bg-purple-700;
  }
}
```

these are the only line of code i used in my project and nothing more.

I want to vertically center the form without effecting any other changes to my form

Comment: add mx-auto class

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution of the problem

```
    <div className="h-screen bg-gray-100 p-10 grid grid-cols-1  ">
      <div className="place-self-center">
        <form className=" grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 p-9  rounded-xl  shadow-xl  bg-gray-50 max-w-sm mx-auto  ">
          /* ..... some context ....*/
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

if we wrap our form into two divs and make parent div(div1) a grid and by using `place-self-center` class on child div(div2) then the size will not be effected and the context will automatically place in the vertical middle of the screen

```
<div className="h-screen  grid grid-cols-1" >
    1
  <div className="place-self-center" >
      2
     <form>
         context
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```